# Find whether a given document contains list of words

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to find whether a given document contains list of words. 
For example,

```
list_of_words = [ 'stackoverflow', 'sun' ]
data = "stackoverflow is awesome"
```

Expected output is `('stackoverflow', 1)`. ie `( word, position_of_the_word)`.

Size of list_of_words is of the order 2000-3000.

I am working on optimizing the exiting code. Existing code forms regular expression from list_of_words and finds them in data. Implementation is in python.

Any suggestion to optimize this problem is welcome.

Comment: It's hard to optimize code that we can't see.

Comment: Is position of the word by byte offset or word offset? i.e., would you expect `('is', 2)` or `('is', 14)`

Comment: If `list_of_words` is 2000 to 3000 words, how big is data? What is wrong with the way you are doing it now?

Comment: The standard solution is the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). A Google search will reveal several python implementations.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to use the [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) function and a list comprehension.  Without knowing your exact needs it is difficult to optimize your code.  For example, what if `stackoverflow` appeared twice in the data string.  What is the desired output?

```
list_of_words = [ 'stackoverflow', 'sun' ]
data = "stackoverflow is awesome"

print [(word, data.find(word)+1) for word in list_of_words if word in data]
```

Results:

```
[('stackoverflow', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the list of words as one list, and all the words from the document as another, you can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/bisect.html) module to find the first word in the word list in the document, then use that as the starting location for the next.

Answer (score 0):

Build [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) Tree on your list_of_words, then apply the document to the Trie

Comment: That's what the Aho-Corasick algorithm does: it builds an optimized trie.